# Converting column headers to rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, pivot-table

I was looking at [Apple Mobility Trends Reports](https://www.apple.com/covid19/mobility) and I have a question on how to put all the dates in one column called "Dates", where each date is a value in the column "Dates". My plan is to set this column as the index for the DataFrame.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: How are you getting this data?

Comment: I just download the csv file from the website and do pd.read_csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
 df.set_index(['geo_type', 'region', 'transportation_type']).T.rename_axis('Dates')
```